# Not understanding what this error code means

Tags: c, pointers

```
    else if (strcmp("read_bin", cmd) == 0) {
        scanf("%s", cmd);
        if (echo) {
            printf("read binary %s\n", cmd);
        }
        book = read_gradebook_from_binary(cmd);
    }
    else if (strcmp("class", cmd) == 0) {
        if (echo) {
            printf("class name \n");
        }
        char *bookName = get_gradebook_name(book);
        printf("class name is %s \n", bookName);
    }
    else if (strcmp("clear", cmd) == 0) {
        if (echo) {
            printf("clear  all memory \n");
        }
        free_gradebook(book);
    }
```

The error code I keep getting says

```
gradebook_main.c:134:20: warning: initializing 'char *' with an expression of type 'const char *' discards qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
            char * bookName=get_gradebook_name(book);
```

I am not sure why I am getting the error and I am just confused about it.

Comment: `get_gradebook_name` probably returns `const char*`, but you're assigning that return value to a `char*`. Try `const char* bookName=get_gradebook_name(book);`

Comment: just FYI, it's a "warning" not an error, should not cause compilation issues

Comment: As you can see in above comment, your question requires guessing. Please provide a [mre].

Comment: If you are going to post an incomplete snippet along with an error message that refers to line numbers, it would be convenient if you added line numbers.

Comment: @WilliamPursell After formatting the error message as code, it seems to be clear now which line it refers to.

Comment: The type `const char *` is a pointer that points to constant (= read-only) data of type `char`. This means you are not supposed to modify the data. When you assign it to a `char *`, it now is a pointer to writable data. You can get errors or unexpected behavior if you actually try to modify the data. (The code snippet doesn't.) The compiler warning helps you to avoid such errors. You can ignore it, but I strongly recommend to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is quite explicit: `get_gradebook_name` returns a const pointer to `char` and you store this pointer to a variable of type `char *`, which does not have a `const` qualifier, hence you are effectively discarding the qualifier and an assignment through the pointer `bookName` would be allowed, possibly leading to undefined behavior if the pointed object is stored in read only memory, and causing an undesirable side effect if not.

Change the variable type this way:

```
    const char *bookName = get_gradebook_name(book);
```

Comment: @user17011762: you can accept this answer by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score